# numpy.array indices via argparse - How to do it properly?

Tags: python, numpy, argparse

I want to implement a small module that loads data from a HDF5 file, selects a specific data set and does some calculation on each of the subsets. I decided to use an argparse option for selecting the subsets. 
Is there a better way than using a string and manually parsing it?

The code below should do what I want but it isn't very pretty and is not able to handle inputs like ':-3' yet. There must be a better way!

Thanks!

```
parser.add_argument('--filename', required=True, 
               help='the file to open')
parser.add_argument('--snapshots', default="-1", type=str, 
               help="select snapshots (default: %(default)s) ")
[...]
H5 = tables.openFile(filename)

snapshot = args.snapshots
maxval = len(H5.root.trajectory[:])
if snapshot ==":" or snapshot.lower() == "all":
    snapshot = np.arange(maxval)
elif ':' in snapshot:
    if snapshot.index(':') == 0:
        snapshot = np.arange(int(snapshot[1:]))
    elif snapshot.index(':') == len(snapshot) - 1:
        snapshot = np.arange(int(snapshot[:-1]),maxval)
    else:
        from_to = snapshot.split(':')
        snapshot = np.arange(int(from_to[0]), int(from_to[1]))
else:
    snapshot = int(snapshot)
selected = H5.root.trajectory[snapshot]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to parse a string as well, but make use of `slice` to obtain the slice.

**Updated** (see comments below)

Something along the following lines::

```
def parsesection(snapshot):
    if snapshot == 'all':
        return slice(None)
    try:
        section = int(snapshot)
    except ValueError:
        section = [int(s) if s else None for s in snapshot.split(':')]
        if len(section) > 3:
            raise ValueError('snapshots input incorrect')
        section = slice(*section)
    return section

print(parsesection(':5'))
print(parsesection('5:15'))
print(parsesection('5:15:3'))
print(parsesection('3'))
print(parsesection('5::3'))
print(parsesection('::2'))
print(parsesection('all'))
```

Results:

```
slice(None, 5, None)
slice(5, 15, None)
slice(5, 15, 3)
3
slice(5, None, 3)
slice(None, None, 2)
slice(None, None, None)
```

The `section = slice(*section)` might feel as a trick, but if you look carefully, it shouldn't be hard to understand (I do it mostly because if saves me an `if elif else` series that checks for the length of `section`.

This will not work for multi-dimensional indexing; split on a comma first in that case. And in case you want to allow for ellipsis, you'll have to catch the three dots separately, and return an Ellipsis object instead of a slice.

Comment: I'd replace the `int(s)` with a function that can handle `''` as well (returning `None`).  This allows a `snapshot` like `::2`.  Also do you want to handle `2`?  Should it produce `slice(None,2,None)` or `slice(2,3,None)`?

Comment: @hpaulj correct. In my own code I've catered for this, but I was too lazy too look up that code, so this was (too) quickly done from memory. I'll edit the answer to allow for those possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! I just implemented this in my code. Just a follow-up question: if I call my program : `prog.py --snapshots -10:` argparse seems to interpret the `-10:` as an option itself and raises `prog.py: error: argument --snapshots: expected one argument`. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1538164 I don't get this problem. My argparse version is 1.1 (Python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2). Could you check your argparse version, and try this with the simplest script that only takes `--snapshots` as an option? If you're stuck with that problem, just post a new question.

Comment: Do you have any other optionals (arguments) defined?  For example, defining a '-1' argument, makes it interpret all negative numbers as optionals.

Comment: @user1538164 You might be running into [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue9334). So there are two solutions/workarounds: one is to quote your value and start it with a space (`--snapshots "-10:"`), the other (better, imo) solution is to use an equal sign: `--snapshots=-10:`. It can be confusing for an unprepared user, but then again, an equal sign generally goes together with a long option.